# splitstackshape to split text based on different line separators \n for columns and observations

Tags: r, splitstackshape

I have some text data which looks like:

```
> myData
                                                                                                                                                                keyColumn
1 \n\n\n\nCol1\n\nCol1 result.\n\n\n\nCol2\n\nResult col2.\n\n\n\nCol3\n\n-\n\n\n\nCol4\n\nresult col4\n\n\n\ncol5\n\n€result col5\n\n\n\nCol6\n\nresult col6\n\n\n\n\n\n
```

It is structured and I would like to split the text into columns. The structure is always the same. That is, given:

```
\n\n\n\nCol1\n\nCol1 result.
```

It follows that the column name should come after the 4 line separators and the result comes after the 2 line separators.

I have tried using the `splitstackshape` package.

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(myData, splitCols = "keyColumn", sep = "\n\n\n\n", direction = "wide")
```

Which gives:

```
   keyColumn_01 keyColumn_02 keyColumn_03 keyColumn_04 keyColumn_05 keyColumn_06 keyColumn_07 keyColumn_08 keyColumn_09 keyColumn_10 keyColumn_11 keyColumn_12
1:         Col1 Col1 result.         Col2 Result col2.         Col3            -         Col4  result col4         col5 €result col5         Col6  result col6
```

Which isn't exactly what I wanted but close.

Expected output:

```
Col1           Col2            Col3     Col4          col5           Col6
Col1 result    Result col2      -      result col4   €result col5    result col6
```

Data:

```
myData <- structure(list(keyColumn = "\n\n\n\nCol1\n\nCol1 result.\n\n\n\nCol2\n\nResult col2.\n\n\n\nCol3\n\n-\n\n\n\nCol4\n\nresult col4\n\n\n\ncol5\n\n\200result col5\n\n\n\nCol6\n\nresult col6\n\n\n\n\n\n"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    -1L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In base R you could do:

```
read.csv(text=gsub("\n{2,}",",",gsub("\n{4}","\n",myData$keyColumn)), header = FALSE)
    V1           V2
1 Col1 Col1 result.
2 Col2 Result col2.
3 Col3            -
4 Col4  result col4
5 col5 €result col5
6 Col6  result col6
```

From this, you could be able to transpose and format it the way you want

Answer (score 1):

As in Onyambu's answer, the best approach is to first somehow get the data into a long format and then convert it to a wide format. Here's one approach:

```
cSplit(myData, "keyColumn", "\n", "long")[, 
  list(col = keyColumn[c(TRUE, FALSE)], val = keyColumn[c(FALSE, TRUE)])][, 
  dcast(.SD, ... ~ col, value.var = "val")]
#    .         Col1         Col2 Col3        Col4         col5        Col6
# 1: . Col1 result. Result col2.    - result col4 €result col5 result col6
```

Alternatively, in base R you can also do something like:

```
x <- strsplit(trimws(myData$keyColumn), "\n+")[[1]]
data.frame(setNames(as.list(x[c(FALSE, TRUE)]), x[c(TRUE, FALSE)]))
#           Col1         Col2 Col3        Col4         col5        Col6
# 1 Col1 result. Result col2.    - result col4 €result col5 result col6
```